# React Socketio won't proparly update ui

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I have an issue with react won't update ui, I am trying to update the number of people connected in the same `room` there's no issue in the backend, my issue is on the front because I saw that the events are reaching the client through chrome dev tools.
as shown below the event is indeed reaching the client.

[image]

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SocketContext } from '../context/socket';

type Props = {};

export default function Game({}: Props) {
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [playerCount, setPlayerCount] = useState(0);
  const updatePlayerCount = (...args: string[]) => {
    console.log(args);
    setPlayerCount(args.length);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit('join_room', id);
    socket.on('game_result', gameHandler);
    socket.on('player_count', updatePlayerCount);
    return () => {
      socket.off('game_result');
      socket.off('player_count');
    };
  }, []);

  const gameHandler = (...args: any) => {
    console.log(args);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Game {id}
      <div>{playerCount}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

checking the console I do see my `console.log` firing...

[image]

however the first join event does work cause I don't see 0 I see 1 instead. `playerCount = 0` initially

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently I didn't pay attention that the data emitted was an array embedded inside an array
a simple fix was

```js
      setPlayerCount(args[0].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining both your event handlers inside your useEffect() like this

```
useEffect(() => {

const updatePlayerCount = (...args: string[]) => {
    console.log(args);
    setPlayerCount(args.length);
  };

const gameHandler = (...args: any) => {
    console.log(args);
  };

    socket.emit('join_room', id);
    socket.on('game_result', gameHandler);
    socket.on('player_count', updatePlayerCount);
    return () => {
      socket.off('game_result');
      socket.off('player_count');
    };
  }, [id]);
```